# Copy data from one sheet to another and transpose in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use VBA to copy data from one work sheet to another and transpose the data,
Row one as the header data
Column 1 has multiple unique vales (ID)
Column 2 has dates
The rest of the columns has data
Since there is multiple dates for one unique ID and multiple values. I will need to rename the header information  to coincide
End result is to look something like this

ID   Data_1 Date_1 Data_1_2 Date_2  Data_1_3 Date_3 Data_2  Date_1  Data_2_1 Date_2 Data_2_2 Date_3

i tried this but I think i am way off

```
Sub CopyCells()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet, desWS As Worksheet, fnd As Range
    Set srcWS = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set desWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With srcWS
        Set fnd = .Range("I:I").Find("N", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
            .Range("D" & fnd.Row).Resize(, 3).Copy desWS.Cells(desWS.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(5)
            .Range("D" & fnd.Row).Resize(, 5).Copy
            desWS.Cells(desWS.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        End If
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is basically taking (panel) data in the "Long Format" and convert it to the "Wide Format" ([Mode details](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/wide-and-long-data/)).

Using these terms, I found a a forum post similar to your question:
[Reshaping Panel Data (long to wide)](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/reshaping-panel-data-long-to-wide.670802/)

It doesn't try to do the same thing as you are exactly, but it's a good start.
It tells you that there is a way to do this with a Pivot Table or with VBA.

Example data located in cell A1 of sheet "Source":

| ID | Year | VarA | VarB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022 | 9 | 4 |
| 1 | 2023 | 7 | 3 |
| 2 | 2021 | 3 | 9 |
| 2 | 2022 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 2023 | 8 | 3 |
| 3 | 2021 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 2022 | 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 2023 | 1 | 4 |

### Pivot table

Usig the example data as source, you could create a pivot table and configure it as below to get the data in the wide format by unique id:

[image]

### VBA

If you need to use VBA, I've edited the code from the forum post to make it more general. There is still more to do to make it work in the general case, but it should work for your case without too much modifications:

```vb
Sub ConvertLongFormatToWideFormat()

    'Replace this list with the list of columns you have
    'Make sure that IDs and Dates are before the data points (Variable A, B, etc.)
    Dim headers() As Variant
    headers = Array("ID", "Date", "VarA", "VarB")
    
    'Number of columns containing ids
    Dim IdColNb As Long
    IdColNb = 1
    
    'Number of columns containing time
    Dim TimeColNb As Long
    TimeColNb = 1
    
    'This array should contain the list of all possible date as string
    'If you need to list them as data instead of string, make sure you adjust the Application.Match below
    Dim PossibleTimeValues() As Variant
    PossibleTimeValues = Array("2021", "2022", "2023")
    
    Dim PossibleTimeValuesNb As Long
    PossibleTimeValuesNb = UBound(PossibleTimeValues) - LBound(PossibleTimeValues) + 1
    
    'Number of columns containing variables
    Dim VarColNb As Long
    VarColNb = 2
    
    Dim TotalColNb As Long
    TotalColNb = IdColNb + PossibleTimeValuesNb * VarColNb
    
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set SourceSheet = Sheets("Source")
    
    With SourceSheet
        Dim Rng As Range
        Set Rng = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    ReDim FinalData(1 To Rng.Count, 1 To TotalColNb)
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Dim MyCell As Range
        For Each MyCell In Rng
            Dim UniqueId As String
            UniqueId = MyCell.Value2
            
            Dim Col As Variant 'This variable hold the relative position for the date column
            Col = Application.Match(CStr(MyCell.Offset(, 1)), PossibleTimeValues, 0)
            
            If IsError(Col) Then
                MsgBox "Error with time " & CStr(MyCell.Offset(, 1)) & " not found in the possible time values"
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            Dim FinalRowPosition As Long
            If Not .Exists(UniqueId) Then
                Dim n As Long
                n = n + 1
                .Add UniqueId, n
                FinalRowPosition = n
                FinalData(n, IdColNb) = UniqueId
            Else
                FinalRowPosition = .Item(UniqueId)
            End If
            
            'Fill all the values for the specific date we are at
            Dim j As Long
            For j = 1 To VarColNb
                FinalData(FinalRowPosition, IdColNb + Col + PossibleTimeValuesNb * (j - 1)) = MyCell.Offset(, IdColNb + TimeColNb + (j - 1))
            Next
            
        Next
        
        Dim i As Long
        i = .Count
        
    End With
    
    Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet
    Set DestinationSheet = Sheets("Dest")
    
    Dim NewHeaders() As Variant
    ReDim NewHeaders(1 To TotalColNb)
    
    'Get the IDs column
    Dim k As Long
    For k = 1 To IdColNb
        NewHeaders(k) = headers(k - 1)
    Next k
    
    For k = IdColNb + 1 To TotalColNb
        'Note: Here we substract by one at the end since the VBA Array() function returns a zero-based array.
        NewHeaders(k) = headers(k Mod VarColNb + (IdColNb + TimeColNb + 1) - 1) & "_" & PossibleTimeValues(PseudoModulo(k - IdColNb, PossibleTimeValuesNb) - 1)
    Next k
    
    With DestinationSheet.Range("A1")
        .Resize(, TotalColNb) = NewHeaders
        .Offset(1).Resize(i, TotalColNb) = FinalData
    End With

End Sub

'This function is used when a regular modulo operator can't be used because we need to return the Divisor instead of zero
'when the Dividend is divisible by the Divisor
Function PseudoModulo(ByVal Dividend As Long, ByVal Divisor As Long) As Long
    
    PseudoModulo = Dividend Mod Divisor
    
    If PseudoModulo = 0 Then
        PseudoModulo = Divisor
    End If

End Function
```

Running this macro should give you the following in sheet "Dest" :

[image]